# Get selected radio button value with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form on my webpage that looks like this:

```
<form id="numberForm">
<input type="radio" name="number" value="singular"> singular <br>
<input type="radio" name="number" value="plural"> plural <br>
</form>
```

How do I pull the value of the currently selected radio button (without a submit action) in Javascript?
What I'd like is something along the lines of the following:

```
var formInput = document.getElementById("numberForm");
var numberInputValue = formInput.SELECTEDBUTTON.value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very close, you just need to use the `name` of the radio button group in place of "SELECTEDBUTTON", in this case `"number"`:

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var formInput = document.getElementById("numberForm");
  var numberInputValue = formInput.number.value;
  alert(numberInputValue);
});
```

```html
<form id="numberForm">
  <input type="radio" name="number" value="singular"> singular <br>
  <input type="radio" name="number" value="plural"> plural <br>
  <button id="btn">Click</button>
</form>
```